# Event-based Socket Channel java

Tags: java, tcp, server

So I have a status monitor in Java, where each time a "run" in a contest in completed an event or packet is sent to my status monitor. However, the status monitor can also send a packet/event to emergency stop the contest.

(This is just a temp demo so don't worry about the events too much.)

How can I get this to work using Socket or SocketChannel?

Comment: Block on the socket waiting for data? (This question could really use some code examples, btw.)

Comment: @markspace But I want to be able to also send data while I'm waiting.

Comment: `Socket` has two streams.  Call `getInputStream` and block on that.  If you need to send data, call `getOutputStream` and send the data.  TCP/IP is full duplex and can read/write concurrently, there's no problem there.  If you mean on the CPU side, you either have to use multi-threading or non-blocking IO.  I find blocking IO easier so I usually use that.

Comment: @markspace So I have the ServerSocket where I called .accept() on. That is going to be in it's own thread, but how do I handle reading and writing simultaneously? Do I need 1 Socket on each thread? Or can I call both getIn/OutStream() methods in a single thread?

Comment: There are lots of examples on the web.  I really don't feel inclined to write code for you.  Just read up and fit one example to your needs.

Comment: @markspace Is http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html a good resource?